# Login Authentication Issue in Angular 2or

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, authentication

i am trying to authenticate my login page with the code below. When i try to login, i get an error "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". After debugging, the error points to the line of code "let token:string = response && response.json().token;". What could be the problem in my code. Thank you in advance

```
//Authentication Service

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        // set token if saved in local storage
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    }

    login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/crm_api/v1/user/login', JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let token:string = response && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    // set token property
                    this.token = token;

                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({email: email, token: token}));

                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    logout(): void {
        // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
        this.token = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
//login 
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpService} from "../Services/HttpService";
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
import {AuthenticationService} from '../AuthenticationService/authenticationService'





@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    styleUrls:['app.logincomponent.css'],
    templateUrl : './app.logincomponent.html',
    providers:[AuthenticationService]
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit{
    loading = false;
    error = '';



    public redirectUrl: string = '/dashboard'; //Here is where the requested url is stored

    // constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}


    constructor(private auth:AuthenticationService, private router: Router)  {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.auth.logout();
    }


    login = {

        email: "",
        password: "",

    };

    //login user credentials to authenticate
    submitForm() {



        this.loading = true;
        this.auth.login(this.login.email, this.login.password)
            .subscribe(data => {
                if(data == true){
                    //login successful
                    this.redirect();

                }else {
                    this.error = "Username or Password is Invalid";
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            });



    }

    //redirect user after a successful login
    public redirect(): void {

        this.router.navigate([this.redirectUrl]); //use the stored url here

    }

}
```

//error

```
{"_body":"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title>CRMDirectory</title>\n  <base href=\"/\">\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css\">\n  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>\n  <script src=\"https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js\"></script>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css\" />\n\n\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css\" />\n\n\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css\" />\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css\" />\n  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../systemjs.config.js\"></script>\n  <script>\n    System.script('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });\n  </script>\n\n  <link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">\n</head>\n<body>\n  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"inline.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts.bundle.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"main.bundle.js\"></script></body>\n</html>\n","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"Content-Type":["text/html; charset=UTF-8"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost:4200/"}  main.bundle.js:53996:13
EXCEPTION: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data  main.bundle.js:48941:9
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  main.bundle.js:48946:13
Body</Body.prototype.json@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:51328:20
AuthenticationService</AuthenticationService.prototype.login/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:53997:37
MapSubscriber</MapSubscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:10791:22
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:498:13
XHRConnection/this.response</onLoad@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:51143:21
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:107486:21
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:35285:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:107485:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:107375:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:107556:28
  main.bundle.js:48947:13
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

//server

```
 public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required | email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try{
            $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);

            if(! $token){
                return response()->json([
                    'msg' => 'Invalid Credentials',
                    'retry' => true
                ], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e){
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Could not create token',
                'retry' => true
            ], 501);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'retry' => false,
            'status' => 'active'
        ], 200);

    }
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` just before `let token..` line ?

Comment: `Observable<boolean>` are you expecting just boolean value or the token itself.

Comment: @Jai i am trying to get the token since i was getting the error " token_not_provided"

Comment: is the data coming from Response correct..?

Comment: then you are having a problem with your server reponse...its not returning a valid json string..you need to have a proper json data for response.json() to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an Angular problem!

Your code would work, but your web-api doesn't response with a valid JSON string!

Its responsing with HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title>CRMDirectory</title>\n  <base href=\"/\">\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css\">\n  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>\n  <script src=\"https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js\"></script>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css\" />\n\n\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css\" />\n\n\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css\" />\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css\" />\n  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"../systemjs.config.js\"></script>\n  <script>\n    System.script('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });\n  </script>\n\n  <link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">\n</head>\n<body>\n  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"inline.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts.bundle.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"main.bundle.js\"></script></body>\n</html>\n
```

Check that URL or modify your server to response with valid JSON.. :)

Comment: could you please help me understand your answer....the statement " check that url"

Comment: maybe you are posting to the wrong URL. The problem is definitly in the Server side. Your server needs to answer the Login request with JSON instead of auch HTML Page.. :)

Comment: I am sure the URL is right because when i don't take care of the token and i just decide to authenticate just the email and password, i am able to login and in the console, i see that the token is being created. But since i am not taken care of the token, it will then give the error " token_not_provided" when i try to do a get request

Comment: your posted response is HTML, your posted code should return JSON.. try to test it with Postman..